# Style being set but not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, scss-lint

### UPDATE: I have read that in Angular, you cannot manipulate the DOM. What are you supposed to do then, what is best practice? I have tried using a timeout, NgZone, ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges() all with no success.

I have an **html** img element:

```
<img class="selected" id="icon-image-{{item.id}}" src="{{item.icon}}" height="75" width="75" />
```

and some **sccs**:

```
img.selected {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

When this loads, it applies the selected class, and makes the image grey as expected.

However, when I run the following **typescrpt** the image just stays grey:

```
let imgEl: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('icon-image-' + subCategoryModel.id);
imgEl.className = "";
```

When I log the className, it shows selected is there before, and has been removed after.

```
console.log(imgEl.classList);
```

Any ideas why, even though I remove a className, the style is not reflected?

When I look at the source code, it is not updating the DOM, but imgEl.classList is being changed. Do you know why?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Something strange, if I change the className in the DOM manually (in Firebug for example), it reflects the change. However, as soon as I click the image, it updates to what the original value was. It is as if the DOM is being refreshed.

If this is the case, then how is it possible to update the DOM dynamically? Because the DOM refresh just overwrites all changes.

Html

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let trio of getTriples()">
    <ion-col *ngFor="let item of trio" (click)="itemTapped(item)">
      <center>
      <div class="row responsive-md">
        <img class="selected" id="icon-image-{{item.id}}" src="{{item.icon}}" height="75" width="75" />
      </div>
      </center>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Typescript

```
  itemTapped(subCategoryModel: SubCategoryModel) {
    let idx: number = this.isInArray(this.employeeModel.subCategories, subCategoryModel);
    let imgEl: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('icon-image-' + subCategoryModel.id);
    if (idx >= 0) {
      this.employeeModel.subCategories.splice(idx, 1);
      imgEl.setAttribute("class", "");
    } else {
      this.employeeModel.subCategories.push(subCategoryModel);
      imgEl.setAttribute("class", "selected");
    }
    console.log('icon-image-'+subCategoryModel.id+' ('+imgEl.id+'): ' + document.getElementById('icon-image-' + subCategoryModel.id).className);
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to create an [mcve]. Fundamentally, clearing `className` will remove all classes from an element, and thus remove any styling applied by those classes.

Comment: "When I look at the source code, it is not updating the DOM, but imgEl.classList is being changed. Do you know why?" If you view source code in Firefox, you get the initial state of the page, not the latest, so any changes through JS are not reflected. I think Chrome may give you the latest. At any rate, if you just open the developer tools, that would be a live view of what the effectively HTML is.

Comment: Thanks, I will try in Chrome.  I have added an UPDATE to the question I ask that says that the DOM seems to be reset. p.s. I am using Ionic 2.

Comment: Tried it in Chromes Developer Tools, and the DOM does not change when `imgEl.setAttribute("class", "");` is executed.

Comment: Is this a scope issue, am I updating the wrong document? What's the answer, I'm confused. Appreciate any help.  I do a simplified version in jsfiddle and it works, so I think this maybe has something to do with Ionic2?

Comment: How do you do `$scope.$apply()` in Ionic2 typescript?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution:

**html**

```
      <img class="item-stable" id="icon-image-{{item.id}}" src="{{item.icon}}" height="75" width="75" (click)="toggleItem(item)" [class.item-selected]="item === itemShown"/>
```

**ts**

```
  isItemShown(item: SubCategoryModel) {
    return this.itemShown === item;
  }

  toggleItem(item: SubCategoryModel) {
    if (this.isItemShown(item)) {
      this.itemShown = null;
    } else {
      this.itemShown = item;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a deselected class to the element.

Add the required css to that.

Somewhat like this

```
let imgEl: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('icon-image-' subCategoryModel.id);
imgEl.className = "deselected";
```

css

```
img.deselected {
  /* your css here */
}
```

Comment: Hi vishak, thanks for your feedback. I tried that (adding `img.deselected`) with no success.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks vishak, I have posted a solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ng-class`.

[Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

[A simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-class)